# Designing Aggregate Roots with Logic Spanning over Roots

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, eventual-consistency

[image: Diagram]

This seems like a common scenario that someone must have solved by now!

I have a setup where a Company may have a set of Default Roles assigned, and Users of that Company should inherit those roles. User may also have additional roles assigned at the user level, or inherited roles removed at the user level.

Both Company and Users seem like candidates for Aggregate Roots. However when assigning or removing roles from User, I need to query the roles assigned to the corresponding Company. Eventual Consistency is not an option in this case.

What is the best way to design AggregateRoots in this kind of scenario?

Comment: "Both Company and Users seem like candidates for Aggregate Roots" - of which aggregate? What is your aggregate? In DDD you don't design aggregate roots by themselves, you design *aggregates*, and you pick a public-facing object within that aggregate (that we call an aggregate root) to act as the interface to the aggregate.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thank you, yes I agree. In my case I think I need two aggregates CompanyAggregate and UserAggregate and Company and User can be the roots of those Aggregates.
But User needs to know Company.Roles in order to Add/Remove roles from itself.
Does that make sense?

Comment: So, if that's the case, why aren't your aggregates `{Company + companyRoles:List<Role>}` and `{User + userRoles:List<Role>}` (just giving one possible option, as an example)? Then just ask one root if its internal list contains the role you're interested in (maybe pass it in as a parameter to a method on the other one).

Comment: Let’s say there’s a method on User called AssignRole that grants the user access to that role regardless of whether the company also has that role. Is there really a reason the know the default company roles at that point?

Comment: Can you clarify your goal? I have different answers depending on what you are trying to achieve. Are you asking how we can make the system you are describing consistent? Or if there is an alternate design that would avoid this situation?